# using a variable inside quotation marks in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('images[0]')";
```

I want to set the backgroundImage of the CSS body element as the image i have stored in `image[0]`, however whenever I try to do so I get an error in the javascript console saying `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

I assume this is because it is looking for an image called `'images[0]'` which doesn't exist and so I get an error. How can I set it so that it reads the image that is actually stored in `images[0]`?

Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find any other questions like it when I looked.

Comment: Have you tried `"url("+images[0]+")";`

Comment: what about [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this simple lines:

I'm pretty sure you are missing the `"` quotes. So you can combine your `variable` and the `"url()"` using the **Plus character** (+) to get something like this:  `"url('"+images[0]+"')"`

---

```js
let images = ["https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/643819371656294405/F-pVCbHg_400x400.png"]

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+images[0]+"')";
```

Or another way could be to use a way modern technique using this line [(See the docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
let images = ["https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/643819371656294405/F-pVCbHg_400x400.png"]

document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[0]}')`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[0] + ")";` instead.

With ES2015 you can also achieve it with backticks `
Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Modern JS has [*template literal syntax*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that gives string interpolation capabilities.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[0]}')`;
```

As you can see, the *template literal* is delimited with a pair of outer backticks instead of the typical single or double quotes.

The interpolation in a *template literal* happens by enclosing the expression that should be evaluated within the `${}` delimiter. The result of the expression becomes the injected value.

Answer (score 0):

With modern JavaScript it's achieved with [template literals.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

So you can do the following:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[0]}')`;
```